# How to know the user who modified the table in mysql

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-update

I have a question on mysql tables and users. I need to know which user modified a table. I have 2 tables.

```
   1. user (id,username, password and dtime)
   2. author (surname,firstname,email,phone, LastModified, userID)
```

LastModified is the field which writes the timestamp when an update is made. 
I want to be able to write the user id of the current user so I can know the user who made the update. User id is a foreign key in the table 'author'.

Anyone has ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something MySQL can do, unless your users also have mysql accounts that they're using. You will have to modify your client-side code to include the ID of the user on whose behalf the code is running the query, e.g

```
UPDATE author Set surname='Foo', LastModified=now(), userID=$userID
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

MySQL has absolutely NO awareness of what's going in your client-side code, so it's up to you to provide these sorts of details.

If you do have per-user MySQL accounts, then it'd be as simple as

```
UPDATE author Set surname='Foo', LastModified=now(), userID=USER()
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

but providing users with direct database logins is almost ALWAYS an incredibly BAD idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marc B, this idea worked for me, i will make another separate table for users so that login and users will be separate, thanks!